# Passing data through Laravel Controller using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have two routes defined like this :

```
Route::get('directeur/qualite', 'Directeur\qualiteController@index')->name('qualite');
Route::get('directeur/qualite/{texte}','Directeur\qualiteController@getResultOfQuestion')->name('getResultQuestion');
```

My Controller have this function :

```
public function getResultOfQuestion(){
    $texte=Input::get('texte');
    $data = DB::table('questions')->where('texte','=',$texte)->value('code');
    return['data'=>$data];
}
```

And I'm doing a request using Ajax like this :

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/emagine/projet1613/public/directeur/qualite/',
         data: {
               texte: encodeURIComponent(str)
               },
         success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                },
         error: function () {
                 alert('La requête n\'a pas abouti');
                 }
         });
```

I would like to get the result of the function defined in the Controller but I can not do it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any particular error thow in above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this

`Controller`

```
public function getResultOfQuestion($texte){
    $data = DB::table('questions')->where('texte','=',$texte)->value('code');
    return response()->json(array('data' => $data));
}
```

`AJAX` request

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
         url: '/emagine/projet1613/public/directeur/qualite/'+encodeURIComponent(str),
         success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                },
         error: function () {
                 alert('La requête n\'a pas abouti');
                 }
     });
```

Comment: How do you use the helper URL in the javascript?

Comment: you have kept in separate js file? then i just edit my answer try that

Comment: @Erylis then please upvote and accept my answer so it help others to find it useful

Answer (score 0):

You should [return response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses):

```
return response()->json(compact('data'));
```